# Integrating homomorphisms of Borel subalgebras

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras, algebraic-groups, lie-theory

Let $G$ be a connected simple complex Lie group and $\mathfrak{g}$ be its Lie algebra. Let us fix a root decomposition, let $\mathfrak{b}_\pm$, $\mathfrak{n}_+$ and $\mathfrak{h}$ be the corresponding choices of Borel subalgebras, nilpotent subalgebras and a Cartan subalgebra. Let $\mathcal{B}_\pm$, $\mathcal{N}_\pm$, $\mathcal{H}$ be the corresponding connected subgroups of $G$.

(update after the discussion in the comments) I have a morphism of Lie algebras $f: \mathfrak{b}_+\rightarrow \mathfrak{b}_+$ constructed from the following procedure: first, start with an isometry $f : \Gamma_1 \rightarrow \Gamma_2$ for some subsets of the chosen set of simple roots $\Gamma_1,\Gamma_2\subseteq \Pi$; then, extend it to $f : \mathbb{Z}\Gamma_1 \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}\Gamma_2$, and then define $f: \mathfrak{b}_+(\Gamma_1) \rightarrow \mathfrak{b}_+(\Gamma_2)$ (Borels generated by $\Gamma_1$ and $\Gamma_2$) via $f(h_\alpha) = h_{f(\alpha)}$ and $f(e_\alpha) = e_{f(\alpha)}$, $\alpha > 0$ (Chevalley basis, let's say). Lastly, extend $f$ by zero to $f : \mathfrak{b}_+ \rightarrow \mathfrak{b}_+$. The question is: can it be integrated to a morphism $F : \mathcal{B}_+ \rightarrow \mathcal{B}_+$?

- Since $\mathcal{N}_+\subseteq \mathcal{B}_+$ is always simply connected, it is possible to integrate the morphism at least to $F|_{\mathcal{N}_+} : \mathcal{N}_+ \rightarrow \mathcal{N}_+$.
- We know that $\mathcal{B}_+ = \mathcal{N}_+ \rtimes \mathcal{H}$, so if it were possible, under some conditions, to define $F|_{\mathcal{H}} : \mathcal{H} \rightarrow \mathcal{H}$, it would be possible, I guess, to extended it to $F:\mathcal{B}_+ \rightarrow \mathcal{B}_+$. Under what conditions would it be possible?

Comment: $\mathfrak{h} \cong \mathcal{H}$? $\  \mathcal{H}$ is a complex torus, isomorphic to $\Bbb{C}^{*n}$.

Comment: What is wrong with the following argument: first, $\exp : \mathfrak{h} \rightarrow \mathcal{H}$ is a diffeo from nbd of 0 to a nbd of $e$; second, $\exp$ is surjective because of commutativity of $\mathcal{H}$; third, if $\exp(h_1) = \exp(h_2)$, then $\exp(h_1-h_2) = e$, hence $\exp(\frac{1}{n}(h_1-h_2)) = e$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$, and thus $h_1 = h_2$, because it's a diffeo around $0$.

Comment: Do you believe that $\exp:\mathbb{C}\rightarrow \mathbb{C}^*$ is bijective?

Comment: Well, it's not bijective

Comment: Answer to the edited question: no again. Most homomorphisms $\mathfrak{h}\rightarrow \mathfrak{h}$ are not integrable, $G$ simply connected or not.

Comment: What if we consider a more specific case: given a set of simple roots $\Pi$ and $\Gamma_1,\Gamma_2 \subseteq \Pi$ with $f: \Gamma_1 \rightarrow \Gamma_2$ being an isometry; extend it to $f : \mathfrak{h}_{\Gamma_1} \rightarrow \mathfrak{h}_{\Gamma_2}$, and then extend by zero to $f : \mathfrak{h}\rightarrow\mathfrak{h}$. Is it integrable in this case?

Comment: Crossposted: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4730123/96384 Please make readers aware of crossposts.